# Web Crawler com view.py do Django

Tags: django, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy, scraping

estou fazendo um simples web crawler, usando o django 2.0, eu quero capturar apenas a classe "titulo" das noticias e depois renderizar "return render" para um html simples, segue abaixo minha view.py. No momento estou utilizando o "return HttpRensonse". como posso pegar os dados e renderizar para um html?

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import html
import urllib3

from django.http import HttpResponse #Para apenas fazer testes testes apenas

def crawler(request):
    url = "https://noticias.uol.com.br/"
    response = requests.get(url)
    html = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    return HttpResponse(soup)
```

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com [a documentação do Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#example), a forma de retornar um object `HttpResponse` com um template e contexto é:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader

def my_view(request):
    # View code here...
    t = loader.get_template('myapp/index.html')
    c = {'foo': 'bar'}
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c, request), content_type='application/xhtml+xml')
```